# need code or logic behind hist command in matlab

Tags: java, matlab, equivalent

i need a help.i am using matlab code that uses hist command,i need the java equivalent code or the logic behind hist function in matlab so that i can code it in java or c.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try to `edit hist` and see matlab's way to implement hist.

Comment: There are all kinds of options - different ways in which it can behave (return values, create bins, plot graphs, multiple datasets, annotation...). It would be helpful if you simplified your question - for example, "how to create a C array with a series of bins corresponding to an array X(50,1) where I don't know in advance how many bins I need, but the bins have to be `10` wide and evenly spaced". That we may be able to help with - but for the general case you can follow @natan's advice (but I'm not even sure it will be all that helpful - it is a very complicated function with many options).

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic for histogramming (assuming you have known bins of constant width, and you don't need the most efficient code possible):

```
float x[50]; // assumed to be array of data values
float binWidth, firstBin; // bins of width binWidth; first one centered on firstBin
int numBins; // number of bins
int *bins, tooSmall = 0, tooLarge = 0, ii, indx;

bins = (int*)calloc(numBins * sizeof(int)); // allocate, set to zero

for(ii = 0; ii < 50; ii++) {
  indx = floor((x[ii]-firstBin)/binWidth + 0.5);
  if (index < 0 ) {
    tooSmall++;
    }
    elseif (index >= numBins) {
      tooLarge++;
    }
    else {
      bins[indx]++;
    }
  }
}
```

At the end you have a histogram of the data in `x`, with two counters corresponding to the data that didn't fit in the range (either under, or over range).

Disclaimer: written without compiler to test. Looks "about right" - test it on a known case before relying on it.